# how to index (elasticsearch) only specific collection in a specific mongodb database using mongo-connector.

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I want to index only specific mongodb collection in elastic search using mongo-connector. 
Mongodb server has multiple databases having multiple collections. I dont want to index entire database.

Answer (score 3):

better to have a configuration file as per stated below

https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Configuration-Options

https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/blob/master/config.json

Through mapping, we can redirect the indexes of mongo database:collection to index:index_type

```
    "mapping": {
        "db.collection": "index.index_type",
        "db.source2": "db.dest2"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this option to run specific collection only.

$ mongo-connector -m mongodbserver:27017 -t elasticserver:9200 -d elastic_doc_manager --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt --namespace-set database.collection